# How to write a program for how many days a person has been alive

Tags: vb.net

With the users date  of birth, I have to create a function in visual basic to find out how many days the person has been alive.

```
TextWindow.WriteLine("Please enter the year of your birth (yyyy):")
yearBirthday = TextWindow.ReadNumber()
TextWindow.WriteLine("Please enter the month of your birth (01-12):")
monthBirthday = TextWindow.ReadNumber()
TextWindow.WriteLine("Please enter the day of your birth (01-31):")
dayBirthday = TextWindow.ReadNumber()
```

Comment: Please try rewording your question and adding some more information.  Otherwise, this question will be closed.

Comment: I didn't give a downvote, but my best guess is you are asking us to write a program for you which we don't do, we help solve problems and issues. Also you have not provided any code as to what you have tried so far, please do so if you need help. If not SO isn't the place to ask this kind of question.

Comment: @gordon Hayes I see the update, but clarify what isn't working and such... Also you said you need a function to determine all of this, do you know how to create a function?

Comment: This is all I have so far. I want to know should I use for, select case?

Comment: Yes I know how to function.

Comment: @gordonHayes I would guess this is a console app right?

Comment: It sounds like what you need is to start learning VB.NET from the ground up.  This site is not going to help you to do that.  This site is for asking *specific*, targeted questions -- not to give people a full tutorial on a programming language.

Comment: yes it is a console application

Comment: Just a simple yes im going to help you or no. No need for all that.

Comment: @gordonHayes maybe this will help you: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/assessing-dates-of-birth-using-visual-basic3/ with a quick google search...

Answer (score 0):

The DateDiff function works like this:

```
Dim days = DateDiff("d", "1943-01-02", Now)
```

Or, you can also use the overloaded "-" operator which yields a TimeSpan object:

```
Dim days = (Now - Date.Parse("1943-01-02")).Days
```

Or, you can use one of the Date constructors:

```
Dim days = (Now - New Date(1943, 1, 2)).Days
```